# Why is not TextBlob using / detecting the negation?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I am using TextBlob to perform a sentiment analysis task. I have noticed that TextBlob is able to detect the negation in some cases while in other cases not.

Here are two simple examples

```
>>> from textblob.sentiments import PatternAnalyzer

>>> sentiment_analyzer = PatternAnalyzer()
# example 1
>>> sentiment_analyzer.analyze('This is good')
Sentiment(polarity=0.7, subjectivity=0.6000000000000001)

>>> sentiment_analyzer.analyze('This is not good')
Sentiment(polarity=-0.35, subjectivity=0.6000000000000001)

# example 2
>>> sentiment_analyzer.analyze('I am the best')
Sentiment(polarity=1.0, subjectivity=0.3)

>>> sentiment_analyzer.analyze('I am not the best')  
Sentiment(polarity=1.0, subjectivity=0.3)
```

As you can see in the second example when using the adjective `best` the polarity is not changing. I suspect that has to do with the fact that the adjective `best` is a very strong indicator, but doesn't seem right because the negation should have reversed the polarity (in my understanding).

Can anyone explain a little bit what's going? Is textblob using some negation mechanism at all or is it just that the word `not` is adding negative sentiment to the sentence? In either case, why does the second example has exactly the same sentiment in both cases? Is there any suggestion about how to overcome such obstacles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(edit: my old answer was more about general classifiers and not about PatternAnalyzer)*

TextBlob uses in your code the "PatternAnalyzer". Its behaviour is briefly discribed in that document: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#parser

We can see that:

> The pattern.en module bundles a **lexicon of adjectives** (e.g., good, bad, amazing, irritating, ...) that occur frequently in product reviews, annotated **with scores for sentiment polarity** (positive ↔ negative) and subjectivity (objective ↔ subjective).
>
> The sentiment() function returns a (polarity, subjectivity)-tuple for the given sentence, **based on the adjectives it contains**,

Here's an example that shows the behaviour of the algorithm. The polarity directly depends on the adjective used.

```
sentiment_analyzer.analyze('player')
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)

sentiment_analyzer.analyze('bad player')
Sentiment(polarity=-0.6999998, subjectivity=0.66666)

sentiment_analyzer.analyze('worst player')
Sentiment(polarity=-1.0, subjectivity=1.0)

sentiment_analyzer.analyze('best player')
Sentiment(polarity=1.0, subjectivity=0.3)
```

Professionnal softwares generally use complex tools based on neural networks and classifiers combined with lexical analysis. But for me, TextBlob just tries to give a result based on a **direct result from the grammar analysis** (here, the polarity of the adjectives). It's the source of the problem.

It does **not try to check if the general sentence is negative** or not (with the "not" word). It tries to check **if the adjective is negated** or not (as it works only with adjective, not with the general structure). Here, best is used as a noun and is not a negated adjective. So, the polarity is positive.

```
sentiment_analyzer.analyze('not the best')
Sentiment(polarity=1.0, subjectivity=0.3)
```

Just remplace the order of the words to make negation over the adjective and not the whole sentence.

```
sentiment_analyzer.analyze('the not best')
Sentiment(polarity=-0.5, subjectivity=0.3)
```

Here, the adjective is negated. So, the polarity is negative.
It's my explaination of that "strange behaviour".

---

The real implementation is defined in file:
https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/_text.py

The interresing portion is given by:

```
if w in self and pos in self[w]:
    p, s, i = self[w][pos]
    # Known word not preceded by a modifier ("good").
    if m is None:
        a.append(dict(w=[w], p=p, s=s, i=i, n=1, x=self.labeler.get(w)))
    # Known word preceded by a modifier ("really good").
    
    ...
    

else:
    # Unknown word may be a negation ("not good").
    if negation and w in self.negations:
        n = w
    # Unknown word. Retain negation across small words ("not a good").
    elif n and len(w.strip("'")) > 1:
        n = None
    # Unknown word may be a negation preceded by a modifier ("really not good").
    if n is not None and m is not None and (pos in self.modifiers or self.modifier(m[0])):
        a[-1]["w"].append(n)
        a[-1]["n"] = -1
        n = None
    # Unknown word. Retain modifier across small words ("really is a good").
    elif m and len(w) > 2:
        m = None
    # Exclamation marks boost previous word.
    if w == "!" and len(a) > 0:
    
    ...
```

If we enter "not a good" or "not the good", it will match the else part because it's not a single adjective.

The "not a good" part will match `elif n and len(w.strip("'")) > 1:` so it will reverse polarity. `not the good` will not match any pattern, so, the polarity will be the same of "best".

The entire code is a succession of fine tweaking, grammar indictions (such as adding ! increases polarity, adding a smiley indicates irony, ...). It's why some particular patterns will give strange results. To handle each specific case, you must check if your sentence will match any of the if sentences in that part of the code.

I hope I'll help

Comment: Going through the docs of TextBlob to see how the default sentiment classifier works (PatternAnalyzer is the default classifier) I think you are wrong. The PatternAnalyzer does use grammar analysis. Have a look [here](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/_text.py#L701) if you want to learn more. Shortly it uses a lexicon of annotated words and then performs various mappings between the scores in the lexicon and the properties of the sentences. It is also actively looking for negations as you can see [here](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/en/__init__.py#L83)

Comment: So maybe your answer truly depicts how the other classifiers in TextBlob work, like the NaiveBayerClassifier, but I haven't gone through those parts of the implementation. I  suspect though that grammar analysis is always involved. Either through feature extraction or through other kinds of heuristics.

Comment: Ok, my bad. So, for pattern analysers, the answer would be based on that document: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#parser (the pattern analyser documentation). 

> The sentiment() function returns a (polarity, subjectivity)-tuple for the given sentence, based on the adjectives it contains

So, as not isn't an adjective, it doesn't impact polarity. 
You can check with: "player". It has a null polarity. But, if you do "best player" it will have a unary polarity. "worst player" will give -1

I will add it to my post.

Comment: That may be closer to the correct answer but again I am not completely sure that it's completely correct, or better completely accurate. See, if for example you take the sentiment of the sentence 'I am not a best' the negation is successfully applied while `a` and `the` play the exact same role in the sentence according to the textblob pos tagger.

Comment: I think it's because it takes the group "not a best" as a negative adjective. 
For me, it splits "(not a best) player" and "not (the best player)". It's why the first case is negative and the second one is positive. 

But, it's just my interpretation of the problem. Of course, it's very tricky as it's a kind a bug, not a feature. I think I have found why the sentence was a corner case. For a fully explaination, we need to consider the exact implemenatation of the textblob analyzer: 
https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/tree/dev/textblob

Comment: If I go a step further by instpecting the source code, here: 
https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/_text.py

I found on lines between 890 and 900 that the library works that way. 
If we read a known word, such as "good", take it's polarity. If we read "not " + adjective, set it as negative. If we read not + a + adjective, set it as negative (a can be any one letter word; replace "not a best player" by "not a z player", it also works). If you read the entire if case on that portion of code, you will see that no pattern match not + the + adjective. It's why it doesn't work :)